# Does Kademlia iterativeFindNode operation store found contacts in the k-buckets?

Tags: algorithm, kademlia

Following the Kademlia specifications found at [XLattice](http://xlattice.sourceforge.net/components/protocol/kademlia/specs.html), I was wondering the exact working of the **iterativeFindNode** operation and how it is useful for bootstrapping and refreshing buckets. The document says:

> At the end of this process, the node will have accumulated a set of k active contacts or (if the RPC was FIND_VALUE) may have found a data value. Either a set of triples or the value is **returned to the caller**. (§4.5, Node Lookup)

The found nodes will be returned to the caller, but the specification don't specify what to do with these values once returned. Especially in the context of refresh and bootstrap:

> If no node lookups have been performed in any given bucket's range for tRefresh (an hour in basic Kademlia), the node selects a random number in that range and does a refresh, an iterativeFindNode using that number as key. (§4.6, Refresh)
>
> A node joins the network as follows: [...] it does an iterativeFindNode for n [the node id] (§4.7, Join)

Does running the **iterativeFindNode** operation in itself enough to refresh k-buckets of contacts, or does the specification omits that the result should be inserted in the contact buckets?

Note: the **iterativeFindNode** operation uses the underlying RPC and through them can update the k-buckets as specified:

> Whenever a node receives a communication from another, it updates the corresponding
>   bucket. (§3.4.4, Updates)

However, only the recipient of the FIND_NODE RPC will be inserted in the k-buckets, and the response from that node (containing a list of k-contacts) will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

> However, only the recipient of the FIND_NODE RPC will be inserted in the k-buckets, and the response from that node (containing a list of k-contacts) will be ignored.

I can't speak for XLattice, but having worked on a bittorrent kademlia implementation this strikes me as strange.

Incoming requests are not verified to be reachable nodes (NAT and firewall issues) while responses to outgoing RPC calls are a good indicator that a node is indeed reachable.
So incoming requests could only be added as tentative contacts which have still to be verified while incoming responses should be immediately useful for routing table maintenance.

But it's important to distinguish between the triples contained in the response and the response itself. The triples are unverified, the response itself on the other hand is a good verification for the liveness of that node.

Summary:

**Incoming requests**

- semi-useful for routing table
- reachability needs to be tested

**Incoming responses**

- Immediately useful for the routing table

**Tuples inside responses**

- not useful by themselves
- but you may end up visiting them as part of the lookup process, thus they can become responses